# FastAPI - SQLModel, Relationship and Insertion of New Row leading to Insertion of New Row in Another Table

Tags: postgresql, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

Suppose I have two tables, `Email` and `VStatus` ('V' stands for 'Verification').

```py
class Email(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    email: str
    vstatus_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key='VStatus.id')
    vstatus: Optional["VStatus"] = Relationship()
```

```py
class VStatus(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    vstatus: StatusEnum = Field(default=StatusEnum.Unverified) # InProgress, Verified, Unverified
    vdesc: str = Field(default="") # Verification Description
```

How should I structure my SQLModel tables such that whenever I create a new email via the API say '/create_email', with just a single field `email`, it will automatically created a new row in the `VStatus` table via the `Relationship` defined in the `Email` table?

Example:

```
POST /create_email
{
    'email': 'example@example.com'
}
```

I will get a response that looks like:

```
response = {
    'email': 'example@example.com',
    'vstatus_id': '1001', # example
}
```

And in the `VStatus` table, there will be a new row that looks like:

| id | vstatus | vdesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Unverified | Null |

Comment: Since you haven't given a default value, how do you expect a given value to be set or picked? (Also, generally, there isn't a need for a new row - you need one row for each possible status, not one row for each possible status for each email - so you'd have three rows in `VStatus`, and `Email` would reference one of those three ids instead).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have to create a new table.
You could do something like this:

```
from sqlmodel import Field, JSON, Enum, Column


class Email(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    email: str
    vstatus: VStatus = Field(sa_column=Column(Enum(VStatus)))

class VStatus(str, enum.Enum):
    InProgress = "InProgress"
    Verified = "Verified"
    Unverified = "Unverified"
```